# Rails Tutorial 5.1.1: Static_page/home not showing on server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-adding_to_the_layout

I am using ruby 1.8.7.

static_pages/home no longer shows up on the server when I update app/views/layouts/application.html.erb with the code he provides in listing 5.1.

Original:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

`
Listing 5.1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I even switched back to the Ruby 1.8–style hashes for :media, then :id.

Error I get on the server:

```
compile error
/Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
```

Error when I run test:
Failures:

```
1) Static pages About page should have the h1 'About Us'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/about'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:41

  2) Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/about'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:46

  3) Static pages Home page should have the base title
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:13

  4) Static pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8

  5) Static pages Home page should not have a custom page title
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19

  6) Static pages Contact page should have the h1 'Contact'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/contact'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:55

  7) Static pages Contact page should have the title 'Contact'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/contact'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:60

  8) Static pages Help page should have the h1 'Help'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/help'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:27

  9) Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/help'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       compile error
       /Users/admin/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
       ...nk_to "sample app", '#', :id "logo" );@output_buffer.safe_co...
                                     ^
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:34:in `compile'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:32

Finished in 0.20551 seconds
9 examples, 9 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:40 # Static pages About page should have the h1 'About Us'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:45 # Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:12 # Static pages Home page should have the base title
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7 # Static pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:18 # Static pages Home page should not have a custom page title
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:54 # Static pages Contact page should have the h1 'Contact'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:59 # Static pages Contact page should have the title 'Contact'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26 # Static pages Help page should have the h1 'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:31 # Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
```

I'm sorry if I didn't provide all the information need. I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: You say you switched back to 1.8 style hashes, but you're using 1.9 style hashes in the posted code, what happens if you change the link_to that's failing to `link_to "sample app", '#', :id => "logo"`?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using Ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti Rails installer automatically installed it. I can't update it. Rvm won't let install it. Should I post up another question regarding it?

Comment: @cheeseweasel I did. I tried both. I just posted what the tutorial provided me. I am sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: What error do you get with the 1.8 style hashes, is it exactly the same, because it looks like the error you're getting is to do with the hashes.

Comment: OHHHHHHHH, THANK YOU SOOO MUCH! @cheeseweasel I didn't spot the arrow. I'm not used to the differences, I thought the difference was just the colon in front. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem at all. :) I've added that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is to do with using 1.9 style hashes, you need to change your links to use 1.8 style hashes as follows:

```
link_to "sample app", '#', :id => "logo"
```

Comment: I would vote you up, but my reputation is currently too low. lol. I will surely do so once it raises.